# How do I use the keyboard to "Open a recently used file" in Gedit?

Tags: shortcut-keys, gedit

I want to open a recently used file in Gedit using the keyboard. How do I do that?

The best workaround I've found is to press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> a few times to scroll through the buttons, but that's a pain.

I checked the keyboard shortcuts in the app but didn't see anything. The online [shortcut keys](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-shortcut-keys.html.en) page says "Open the Quick Open window <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>", but that does the same thing as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, so that seems to be wrong or outdated.

I tried holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> to access the title bar buttons by letter, but there doesn't seem to be any letter mapped to the recent files button (as opposed to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>, which maps to the "Open" button).

I found <kbd>F10</kbd> to open the hamburger menu, but there's doesn't seem to be a way to get from there to the other title bar buttons.

If it's relevant, I'm using 20.04.

Comment: Related: [Is it possible to bring back the search box in gedit open recent files dropdown in 20.04?](/q/1285616/301745), [Custom keyboard shortcuts in gedit](/q/223986/301745),

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ended up using the [Quick Open](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/gedit-plugins-quick-open.html.en) plugin. It's installed by default, so simply enable it in the Plugins tab, then press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>. It also lets you search, which is handy.

There doesn't seem to be a keyboard shortcut to open the recent files list. I found [a merge request to add one, from three years ago](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gedit/-/merge_requests/77), but it was closed.

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct shortcut key indeed. You can use:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>O</kbd>
2. <kbd>Left</kbd> to enter the sidebar
3. <kbd>Home</kbd>, <kbd>Enter</kbd> to open the "Recent" list
4. <kbd>Right</kbd> to leave the sidebar

Now you can type part of the name or select a recent file using the arrow keys.

Comment: That's not what I'm looking for, though other folks might find it useful. I only want to see the files I've opened in Gedit, and avoid opening non-text files like PNGs, which Gedit will happily open but maybe freeze/lag in the process. Also, if I do a search in that list then press Esc to close the search box, it actually leaves the list and goes back to the last folder. Lastly, one file that I opened in Gedit doesn't even show in that list, strangely enough.